# How do I find the 3rd angle or a vector with only the two other angles?

Tags: calculus, vectors

A vector has direction angles α = 65° and β = 45°
Find the value of angle γ
Find a vector that has those direction angles

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$cos^2 \alpha + cos^2 \beta + cos^2 \gamma =1$